# How to remove the label of axis of one panel in lattice R

Tags: r, plot, lattice, panels

I have the following test data frame in R:

```
library(lattice)
library(lubridate)
dates <- seq(today()-20, today(), by = 'days')
df <- rbind(data.frame(Date=dates, type = 'First', value = 1),
  data.frame(Date=dates, type = 'Second', value = 2),
  data.frame(Date=dates, type = 'Third', value = 3))
```

I would like to plot *df* using *xyplot* in 3 different panels, where the froups are defined by the *type*, and *value* is plotted against *Date*, where the bottom panel would not have any tick labels while the other two panels would. Here is the code that I used to plot it:

```
xyplot(value ~ Date | type, data = df, type = c("l", "g"), 
  scales = list(x = list(cex = 1), 
                y = list(relation = "free")),
  panel = function(x, y, ..., subscripts) {
    if (panel.number() == 1) {
       panel.axis(at = c(-0.1, 0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4), labels = FALSE, draw.labels = FALSE, ticks = FALSE)
       panel.xyplot(x, y, type = 'l', lwd = 2)
       scales = list(y = list(labels = ""))
    } else {
       panel.xyplot(x, y, type = 'l', lwd = 2)
    }
 },
 layout = c(1, 3),
 abline=list(h=0, lty = 5)
 )
```

However this code did not help. Do any of you know how to solve this issue?
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: To make this reproducible, you might want to remove these characters from your call to `xyplot()`: `x = list(cex = adjust.cex),`

Comment: Yes, you are right. In fact I am using that line in my code, but for this example it has no importance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you are looking for?

```
xyplot(value ~ Date | type, data = df, type = c("l", "g"), 
  scales = list(x = list(cex = 1), 
                y = list(relation = "free",at=list("",seq(0,10,.2),seq(0,10,.2)))),
 layout = c(1, 3),
 abline=list(h=0, lty = 5)
 )
```

This suppresses the ticks and labels in the first panel and manually sets them for the other 2.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I was exactly looking for this. It helped me a lot. Many thanks again.